# on Post requests accept large URLs containing image data in query params

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express to make a web server. I am in a need to create an endpoint which will be accepting image in query params. This image will be in base64. Since the image size can be very large, how can I make my node application to accept very Large URLs.

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, why do you want to accept images as base64-encoded query params in the first place? File uploads should typically come as multipart requests. Also, there is a wonderful npm package called multer that can be used with express to make file uploads easy to implement in node.

Comment: [It looks like](https://github.com/nodejs/http-parser/blob/master/http_parser.h#L55) 80kb is the max URI + header size.. But why would you want to do this to begin with? Why not send the data as part of the body (multipart form data), etc..? Sending in the URL makes little sense to me.

Comment: We have to integrate with a third part service. I do not know why they are sending us data in that format.

Comment: @rainyday how big are the files?

Comment: @MattOestreich < 200 KB